# Using Management classes with cobbler

Tags: configuration-management, provisioning, cobbler

So, I've been working on creating a standardized install image, and worked out all the kinks, now I need to deliver it. What I decided to do is to use cobbler to create templated kickstart installs, but I've hit a bit of a documentation dead-zone: 
Management Classes.

If my theory is correct, I can use management classes to deploy templated configuration files to a newly installed server so I can implement things such as a unified prompt, ldap integration, logging and monitoring, without having to do any actual configuration on the server.

But there's one problem.

I have no idea how to take the management classes I've created and actually use them in my kickstarts. Cobbler's documentation tells how to create file resources, how to create package resources, and how to create management classes, but doesn't say how to implement or use them, that I could find. Google search has only led me to the same three documentation pages that have told me only how to *create* management classes.

So I guess my question is, do management classes do what I think they do, and if so, how do I use them?